# Preventing std::vector from resizing on push_back

Tags: c++, stl

I have a std::vector that I know will never have to grow--it will always have `n` elements (unfortunately, `n` isn't known at compile time so I can't use std::array). I can do:

```
std::vector<blah> v(n);
```

Which correctly sets its capacity to `n`. But when I proceed to fill `v` with `push_back`, it automatically resizes to `2n`.

I realize this is premature optimization, but it's bugging me. Is there a way to set max size or something?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That constructor does not sets the capacity of the vector to `n`, but insteads creates a vector containing `n` objects constructed with `blah`'s default constructor. This can be confusing for people with a Java or .NET background, where `ArrayList` and `List<T>` both have a constructor that sets an initial capacity.

The solution is to do it in two steps:

```
std::vector<blah> v; // create an empty vector
v.reserve(n); // increase capacity
```

Comment: For what it's worth, this won't guard against capacity growth if someone misuses the vector and causes the capacity to double. If you want that kind of safety, you probably need to roll your own class.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, what you want is a `unique_ptr<int[]>`. Standard smart pointers have support for native arrays.

Moreover, as an addition to the accepted answer, do note that if you are using `std::vector`, no-resize is only guaranteed if you explicitly called `reserve`.

> It is guaranteed that no reallocation takes place during insertions that happen after a call to reserve() until the time when an insertion would make the size of the vector greater than the size specified in the most recent call to reserve().

So, the following code snippet won't comply to the standard:

```cpp
// UB
if (v.size() != v.capacity()) {
  // assume no resize
  v.push_back(something);
}
```

In reality, I think most implementations only resize when the capacity is reached.